# How to overload foreach such that it ignores nulls in a 2D array

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array of objects declared like so:

```
public PCE[,] PARR = new PCE[64, 64]; // object is PCE, a piece, PARR is short for piece array. The 2D array is used to quickly get a piece at a certain position on the board.
```

I knew you could use "foreach" to iterate through lists and arrays, so i tried it. Turns out it will iterate through every element, including the nulls (which i guess are considered elements?), which means I hafta do null checking first.

It would be nice to overload the "foreach" operator to do 2 things:

1. exclude nulls
2. bound the foreach not at 63 x 63, but at the particular board size of each level. (64 x 64 is just the maximum board size. Most boards will be considerably smaller.)

Is this possible? I'm using C# MonoGame in Visual Studio 2010.

PS. Before I forget, I want the foreach to iterate in order as if I were doing the following nested loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < bh; j += 1) // bh is board height
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bw; i += 1) // bw is board width
    {
        // this iterates from left to right, then top to bottom
    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking about `foreach`, but your code shows `for` loops. Have you tried a `foreach`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overload `foreach`. It's not a method (operator or otherwise).

You *can* write an iterator method, which you can then call and use the return value of in a `foreach` loop. For example:

```
IEnumerable<T> EnumerateSubMatrix<T>(T[,] array, int width, int height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        yield return array[i, j];
    }
}
```

Then just:

```
foreach (PCE pce in EnumerateSubMatrix(PARR, bw, bh))
{
    // something
}
```

If you want to exclude `null` values, just skip them in the iterator method:

```
IEnumerable<T> EnumerateSubMatrix<T>(T[,] array, int width, int height)
    where T : class
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        T t = array[i, j];

        if (t != null)
        {
            yield return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you have to add a constraint on `T`, to ensure it's a reference type, so that it can even be compared to `null`.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your code. It looks like you're testing if the entire array is null, which is different than testing if one of the elements is null. Also, can you explain what the yield keyword does? If we're returning the entire array, that would really confuse me cuz it's gonna have null elements unless we somehow remove elements from the array, making it jagged or something.

Comment: The local variable `t` is the current _element_ of the array, not the whole array itself. I did forget to edit the `yield return` (copy/paste from the original example I gave), but I've edited the question to clean that up (it would work either way, but the point of the local variable was to avoid dereferencing the array twice). And no, it's not returning the whole array; the `yield` keyword is what makes this method [an iterator method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx). Click the link to read more about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper class and sample code to use it. I used string instead of PCE.

```
public static class BoardExtensions
{
    public class IterationElement<T>
    {
        protected T[,] Board { get; set; }

        public int XPos { get; protected set; }
        public int YPos { get; protected set; }

        public T Element
        {
            get { return Board[XPos, YPos]; }
            set { Board[XPos, YPos] = value; }
        }

        public IterationElement(T[,] board, int x, int y)
        {
            this.Board = board;
            this.XPos = x;
            this.YPos = y;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IterationElement<T>> ValidItems<T>(this T[,] board, int width, int height)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                if (board[x, y] != null)
                {
                    yield return new IterationElement<T>(board, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var board = new string[64, 64];

        for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
            {
                if (random.Next() % 2 == 0)
                {
                    board[x, y] = "OK";
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in board.ValidItems(10, 15))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0},{1}]: {2}", item.XPos, item.YPos, item.Element));
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use a sparse array. Use a `Dictionary<int,PCE>` to store each object and its location. So if the board is `N×N` to designate the `[i,j]` location use key: `i*N+j`.

See example below:

```
public class PCE { }
public class Board
{
    readonly int size;
    readonly Dictionary<int, PCE> pieces;

    public Board(int size)
    {
        this.size=size;
        pieces=new Dictionary<int, PCE>();
    }
    public int Size { get { return size; } }
    public int GetKeyFromPosition(int i, int j) { return size*i+j; }
    public void GetPositionFromKey(int key, out int i, out int j)
    {
        i=key/size;
        j=key%size;
    }
    public void PlacePCE(int i, int j, PCE item)
    {
        pieces[size*i+j]=item;
    }

    public PCE GetPCE(int i, int j)
    {
        if (pieces.ContainsKey(size*i+j))
        {
            return pieces[size*i+j];
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PCE this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return GetPCE(i, j); }
        set { PlacePCE(i, j, value); }
    }

    public bool IsLocationFilled(int i, int j)
    {
        return pieces.ContainsKey(size*i+j);
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<int, PCE>> Pieces
    {
        get
        {
            return pieces.ToList();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Board board=new Board(64);

        board.PlacePCE(4, 7, new PCE());
        board.PlacePCE(11, 2, new PCE());
        board.PlacePCE(2, 47, new PCE());
        board.PlacePCE(51, 37, new PCE());

        if (board.IsLocationFilled(2, 47))
        {
            var pce=board[2, 47];
        }

        // Non-nulls only. Iterates over 4 items only
        foreach (var item in board.Pieces)
        {
            int i, j;
            board.GetPosition(item.Key, out i, out j);
            PCE pce=item.Value;
            // Do something with [i,j] PCE
        }
    }
}
```

### Features:

1. Variable board size (you need to set limits in constructor for `Board`)
2. `GetKeyFromPosition` and `GetPositionFromKey` converts between the 2d coordiantes to a 1d unique key location (and back).
3. `PlacePCE` and `GetPCE` sets a `PCE` type on a board location (or retrieves it). Also `this[int i, int j]` does the same so you can use `Board[,]` indexing
4. `IsLocationFilled` checks if a location already contains an item
5. `Pieces` returns a list of items on the board via a `KeyValuePair`. The pair key is the location index, and the value is the `PCE` instance.